# Make this piecewise function continous and then prove it is continuous on [-1/2, 1/2]

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x \sin(1/x) + a & x < 0 \\
b & x = 0 \\
\frac{\tan{3x}}{x} & x > 0
\end{cases}$

The assignment is as stated in the title. I'm fairly sure about the process of defining the function, but the last part about proving it's continuous on an interval is the weaker part of my work, so any suggestions or input is very welcome. This is what I've got:

The function is continuous when the limit of the three cases in $x = 0$ coincide. In other words, $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\tan{3x}}{x}$ will approach some limit that in $x = 0$ must be $b$ and then $x \sin(1/x) + a$ must also approach this limit $b$. First we determine the limit of $\dfrac{\tan{3x}}{x}$:

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan{3x}}{x}
= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin{3x}}{x \cos{3x}}
= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{\cos{3x}} \frac{3\sin{3x}}{3x}
= 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 1
= 3$

So we have that $b = 3$ and it remains to determine $a$ so that $\lim_{x \to 0} x \sin{1/x} + a = 3$. We make the variable subtitution $t = \dfrac{1}{x}$ and have that
$\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\sin{t}}{t} + a = 3
\implies
0 + a = 3
\implies
a = 3$

We now have that $a = b = 3$ and $f$ can be defined as

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
    x \sin(1/x) + 3 & x < 0 \\
    3 & x = 0 \\
    \frac{\tan{3x}}{x} & x > 0
\end{cases}$

To show that $f$ is continuous on the interval $[-1/2, 1/2]$ we consider a number of subintervals. $f$ is continuous on $[-1/2, 0)$ since $x$, $\sin(1/x)$ and $3$ are continuous and products and sums of continuous functions are continuous. It is continuous in $x = 0$ since the constant function $3$ is continuous.

$f$ is continuous on $(0, 1/2]$ since both $\tan{3x}$ and $x$ are continuous on the interval and quotients of continuous functions are continuous, given the denominator is not $0$. It should be mentioned that $\tan$ is not continous on $\mathbb{R}$ since it has vertical asymptotes at all odd multiples of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ but on our interval $(0, 1/2]$ we have that $1/2 < \frac{\pi}{2}$ which is the first vertical asymptote which means our $\tan{3x}$ is continuous on the interval.

We have shown that $f$ is continuous on all subintervals which means it is also continous on the entire interval $[-1/2, 1/2]$.

Comment: To prove that the function is continuous at $x=0$ you need to note that by construction, the left-hand limit and right-hand limit are the same, and they are the value of the function at $0$.  To see why this is necessary, consider what happens to your "proof" of continuity if you set $b=5$.  Your "proof" still works, but the revised function obviously isn't continuous.

Comment: @RobertShore I'm not sure I follow. That's exactly what I describe but in more words. Or do you mean I should state more clearly that $\tan{3x}/x$ is the right-hand limit and $x \sin{1/x} + a$ the left-hand limit?

Comment: I'm referring to the sentence:  "It is continuous in $x=0$ since the constant function $3$ is continuous."  That's not a proof that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: I see. Do you think it would be better to express this as something like "f is continuous at $x = 0$ since $f(0) = 3$ and both the left-hand and right-hand limits approach $3$ as $x$ approaches $0$."

Comment: Yes, that works.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help!

Answer (score 1):

> It is continuous in $x = 0$ since the constant function $3$ is continuous.

The function $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$ if

$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=f(0)$$

which means that the limit approaching zero from the left equals the limit approaching zero from the right

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$$

and that these limits equal the value of $f(0)$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=f(0)=3$$

You have shown that these three values are the same when $a=b=3$. The only other item that stuck out to me was this sentence.

> $f$ is continuous on $[-1/2, 0)$ since $x$, $\sin(1/x)$ and $3$ are continuous and products and sums of continuous functions are continuous.

The sum and product of a finite number of continuous functions is a continuous function. I think that it was implied that you meant the sum and product of the three continuous functions $x$, $\sin(1/x)$ and $3$.

Comment: Thank you, these are all good comments and has improved the quality of my work.